# Compare between dates in power bi parameters

Tags: sql, powerbi

I have a query like this:

```
select count(distinct userid) as SoftActiveUsers from bookingrequestticket where PickupTime > @start_time
```

and I made "start_time as a date type parameter" and the query is like this:

```
let
Source = Sql.Database("server", "database", [Query="select count(distinct userid) as SoftActiveUsers from bookingrequestticket where PickupTime > "&start_time&" "])
in
Source
```

but the result is:

```
We cannot apply operator & to types Text and Date.
Details:
    Operator=&
    Left=select count(distinct userid) as SoftActiveUsers from bookingrequestticket where PickupTime > 
    Right=1/16/2019
```

so how can i compare with two dates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The & operator only works on text values. You'll need to use converter functions to get text values from your non-text column, or `DateTime.ToText` in this case. Format the date as `YYYYMMDD` to be sure it is recognized properly. Your M code should look like this:

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("server", "database", [Query="select count(distinct userid) as SoftActiveUsers from bookingrequestticket where PickupTime > '" & DateTime.ToText(start_time, "yyyyMMdd") & "'"])
in
    Source
```